# font size for specific file type

Tags: gvim, font

this guy explains how to make a slide presentation in vim: "Giving a Text Based Slide Presentation in Vim without Plugins" https://invidious.osi.kr/watch?v=7fIR55kkTwc

he defines file type .vpm for his slide files and has this script in his vimrc (https://github.com/nickjj/dotfiles/blob/f5495e5e1ff48ddd41782723d19be737fb379fbb/.vimrc#L362-L371):

```
" Mappings to make Vim more friendly towards presenting slides.
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.vpm call SetVimPresentationMode()
function SetVimPresentationMode()
  nnoremap <buffer> <Right> :n<CR>
  nnoremap <buffer> <Left> :N<CR>

  if !exists('#goyo')
    Goyo
  endif
endfunction
```

It makes sense to want a larger font in slides than in other files. Is there anyway to add a line of code to the function above so that it uses a different (larger) font size for this file type (vpm)?

i tried using something like `exec "set guifont=Menlo:16"` which i saw here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127845/dynamic-vim-font-size-based-on-file-length, but it doesnt really work.

I want to use a nerd font. I use gvim. Maybe i should define the function above in my gvimrc?

Comment: This question mainly quotes information seemingly unrelated to the problem, and _"it doesnt really work"_ is not easy to help with. Maybe you would wish to work a bit on rephrasing the question, to have it focus a bit more precise on the issue and include a somewhat more descriptive wording around how the actual outcome differs from the expected one?

Comment: Note that guifont is global and cannot be set per-filetype